# Access 2013 - Sort Irregular lengths strings to oder

Tags: mysql, string, sorting

I'm trying to sort some strings with hexa numbers, my problem is that they are to irregular and hard for my knowledge in Access so I could really use some help!

From every file `"Files"` are one `REQUEST` string with a corresponding `RESPONSE` string they are similar at the first 4 characters `"16xx"` and always at the 8-9 character `"xx"` sometimes in more places and at character 5-6 are `+40` added to the RESPONSE `ex 19 -> 59`. I took some examples from my table (the real table is 600 rows with different string from 24 different files)

`ID = pimekey`, `Files = file where string came form`, `Nr = what nr the string had in file`, `String = the string I would like to sort`, `TYPE = if it was a REQUEST or RESPONSE`

[image]

I would like to make pairs of them in a new query like this...
[image]

...so that they are aliened in `Files` order with the `REQUEST` before the `RESPONSE`.

I have tried making different queries all day to sort this out but can´t get the syntax right. Tried sorting through using SQL `left`, `iif` , `mid`,`len` function with Update queries, but I either get syntax error, nothing or the wrong values... Is there a way of doing this or are they to irregular to even sort?

Thanks

EDIT
from one file how it look now:

```
ID  Files   Nr  String                          Type
1   1       1   1636 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
2   2       2   1637 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
3   2       3   1631 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
4   3       4   1637 19 04 0A 1B 47 FF          REQUEST
28  1       10  1636 59 02 FF                   RESPONSE
29  2       11  1637 59 02 FF                   RESPONSE
30  2       12  1631 59 02 7F C1 00 00 28 C2 A4 RESPONSE
31  3       13  1637 59 04 0A 1B 47 00          RESPONSE
```

how I would want it:

```
ID  Files   Nr  String                          Type
1   1       1   1636 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
28  1       10  1636 59 02 FF                   RESPONSE
2   2       2   1637 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
29  2       11  1637 59 02 FF                   RESPONSE
3   2       3   1631 19 02 2F                   REQUEST
30  2       12  1631 59 02 7F C1 00 00 28 C2 A4 RESPONSE
4   3       4   1637 19 04 0A 1B 47 FF          REQUEST
31  3       13  1637 59 04 0A 1B 47 00          RESPONSE
```

Comment: How are you trying to sort the strings? Strictly by hex value, hex value and Type,...?

Comment: What if you simply ORDER BY Files, Type       or   Files, Nr   ?

Comment: by hex value and from which file it came from, there are more string in every file but i just took "one string pair" from 4 different files @yanman1234

Comment: I do´t know if that would work, but then again i don´t know what would work... I added some files in the question to show more @etsa

Comment: pls don't use images, but post your samples in formatted text

Comment: yes, new to edit @etsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (MYSQL).  It use user defined variable to "generate" field for ordering.  I suppose FIL is the name of the table:

```
SELECT ID, FILES, NR, STRING, TYPE
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    , @o:= CASE WHEN TYPE='REQUEST' THEN @o+2 ELSE 0 END ord
    , @p:= CASE WHEN TYPE= 'RESPONSE' THEN @p+2 ELSE 0 END ord2
    , @o+@p AS ord_tot
    FROM FIL A
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @o:=-1,@p:=2 ) T1
    ORDER BY TYPE, FILES, NR
   ) B
ORDER BY ord_tot;
```

Output:

```
ID  FILES   NR  STRING  TYPE
1   1   1   1636 19 02 2F   REQUEST
28  1   10  1636 59 02 FF   RESPONSE
2   2   2   1637 19 02 2F   REQUEST
29  2   11  1637 59 02 FF   RESPONSE
3   2   3   1631 19 02 2F   REQUEST
30  2   12  1631 59 02 7F C1 00 00 28 C2 A4 RESPONSE
4   3   4   1637 19 04 0A 1B 47 FF  REQUEST
31  3   13  1637 59 04 0A 1B 47 00  RESPONSE
```

Comment: thanks for the help! tried this, but I get "missing operator" in line @o:= CASE WHEN TYPE='REQUEST' THEN @o+2 ELSE 0 END ord

Comment: have you copied all my script well?  Have you tried using the exact names of your table?

Comment: Are you using mysql, as tagged in your question?

Comment: My table name was "tester" so I changed "FIL" to "tester" in your script and then I got the error, so now I tried changing the file name from "tester" to "FIL" and I worked right away? strange... But now it works for all my rows so i´m happy! Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be to use [MySQL's built hexadecimal format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) and then just use `ORDER BY` on the correct fields. This is of course assuming you can modify how your data is stored to conform to the hexadecimal format described.